# Trying to replace Tag <em> with <a>

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup, replacewith

```
import requests
import string
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
[...]
def disease_spider(maxpages):
    i = 0
while i <= maxpages:
    url = 'http://www.cdc.gov/DiseasesConditions/az/'+ alpha[i]+'.html'
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for l in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'noLinking'}):
        x =l.find("em")
        if x is not None:
            return x.em.replaceWith(Tag('a'))

    i += 1
```

Some of the text from the website uses  tags instead of  tags and I wanted to replace them with  tags.
Using this code I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replaceWith'

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to replace `em` with it's text.

In other words, the `a` element containing:

```
<a class="noLinking" href="http://www.cdc.gov/hi-disease/index.html">
    including Hib Infection (<em>Haemophilus influenzae</em> Infection)   
</a>
```

should be replaced with:

```
<a class="noLinking" href="http://www.cdc.gov/hi-disease/index.html">
    including Hib Infection (Haemophilus influenzae Infection) 
</a>
```

In this case, I would locate all `em` tags directly under the `a` tags and, for each `em` tag found, replace it with it's text using `replace_with()`:

```
for em in soup.select('a.noLinking > em'):
    em.replace_with(em.text)
```

---

As a side note, the replacement might not be necessary, because the `.text` of the `a` tag would give you the full text of the node including it's children:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: data = """
   ...:     <a class="noLinking" href="http://www.cdc.gov/hi-disease/index.html">
   ...:         including Hib Infection (<em>Haemophilus influenzae</em> Infection)   
   ...:     </a>
   ...: """

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

In [4]: print soup.a.text

        including Hib Infection (Haemophilus influenzae Infection)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to find all the tags with in the list tag?

Comment: @ks4929 yes. Replace `a.noLinking > em` to, for instance, `li a.noLinking > em`.